# Product of Stirling numbers of second kind

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, stirling-numbers

What does the following expression evaluate to:

$$ k!{n\brace k} \cdot k!{n\brace k} $$

We know that $k!{n\brace k} = n![x^n]:(e^x-1)^k$, where $[x^k]:f(x)$ represents the coefficient of $x^k$ in the power series for $f(x)$. I was wondering if squaring takes us to a different power series or just to a different coefficient in the same power series?

Comment: You are squaring $k! \begin{Bmatrix} n \\ k \end{Bmatrix} $?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yes, I am wondering whether squaring takes us to a different power series or to a different coefficient in the same power series?

Comment: Do you ask about the generating function of the numbers?